# How do I change text body alignment in Sphinx?

Tags: text, format, alignment, python-sphinx

I am using the Sphinx "cloud" theme.  The main body of text has "justified" text alignment, and I want to turn that feature off.  All options for alignment that I see refer to table elements, which is not what I want.

I tried adding an element to the _static/style.css file:

```
body {
    text-align:left;
}
```

but this did not un-justify the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIP: Don't guess at the CSS selector, [inspect the source code](https://bitbucket.org/ecollins/cloud_sptheme/src/default/cloud_sptheme/themes/cloud/static/cloud.css_t) or [through the web](https://cloud-sptheme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/cloud.css).

In your custom override, you will need to override every instance of `text-align: justify;` in the theme. I found three.

```
div.body p {
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 1.5em 0 1.5em 0;
}

div.body li, div.body dd {
    text-align: justify;
}

table.docutils .justify-align {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

This ought to do it:

```
div.body p,
div.body li,
div.body dd,
table.docutils .justify-align {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this has sorted it out.  Thanks for the solution+explanation.